# Interactive brokers: How to retrieve transaction history records?

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

Basically, I want to use python to query my IB order history and do some analyze afterwards. But I could not find any existing API for me to query these data, does anyone have experience to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Interactive Brokers has a documented API. You should attempt to implement a solution and return if you run into specific issues.

Comment: Yes, I know IB has an API but I could find what I want.

Comment: What you want is not done with the api but with account management on the web.
 https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/etmug/employeetrackmgmt.htm#cshid=employeetrack/etreports/ib_activity_flex.htm

Comment: Thanks, Brian, so there are no program ways to retrieve the order history, right?

Comment: You can write a small program to fetch the statements from the internet.  You can also log the orders when you make them and when they are filled so you always have a record.

Comment: @NiucoolKi do you found how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TWS API doesn't have this functionality. You can't retreive order history, but you can get open orders using  recOpenOrders request and  capture executions in  realtime by listening to execDetails event - just write them to a file and analyse  aftewards.

Comment: After searching in the API to find this functionality and spent a lot of time, I stopped now. Useful answer (I voted up)

Answer (score 8):

You have to use flex queries for that purpose. It has full transaction history including trades, open positions, net asset value history and exchange rates.

Comment: what are flex queries?

Comment: @CorneliuMaftuleac https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/allocationfunds/topics/flexqueries.htm

Comment: which of the IB APIs support automated retrieve of these queries?

Comment: @YevKad you can use the flex web service: https://guides.interactivebrokers.com/ap/advisorportal.htm#flexweb3.htm#kanchor618 You will need to generate a token for this purpose. Here is a good reference how to create a web service token: https://webhelp.tradingdiarypro.com/web_service_import.htm